# Superset loading examples don't seem to disable

Tags: apache-superset

I am running Superset in docker. At first the example datasets, charts and so on were loading. After some time I decided to disable examples.

I changed the configuration to `SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=no` in the .env file. I also tried to delete this key from .env. However, examples don't seem to disappear. How can they be deleted completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've run Superset once with `SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes`, that will populate the example data and charts/dashboards into your metadata database alongside any actual charts and data.  My understanding from searching the codebase is that there's no way to undo this.

If you really want those examples gone, you can start fresh from a new metadata db, but that would mean discarding any content you've created.  Or you can try deleting the examples manually, either in the UI or in the database backend.

If you can't start fresh, my personal advice is to just ignore them.  Eventually they'll get pushed to the bottom by your new content, and it's nice to have them in case you need to file a reproducible bug report example.  I tried deleting some of them from the database backend and all I did was corrupt them so I get 500 errors when I try to load the examples.

Comment: Yes, you are comletely right! I have deleted manually in database all rows related to examples, and now it works fine - previously loaded exaples are deleted and the "new ones" are not loaded